# SSH (secure shell) access with apache on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, shell, apache-http-server

Is it possible (and how if it's possible) to setup secure shell access to Apache? Apache is installed on my local computer (Windows)?  I have SSH access in my hosting account, but I need it on my local computer.

Answer (score 6):

ssh and Apache are two completely separate applications and perform different tasks.

You can however set up SSH on Windows which you can then edit files that are being shared by Apache: See questions; [64058](https://superuser.com/questions/64058/windows-ssh-servers), [18292 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows), or [8411 on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)