# Is it possible to open a remote terminal session on a Windows XP machine?

Tags: windows-xp, shell, remote

Remote desktop is... useable, but I'd like to get a proper remote terminal window open on the Windows XP machine, like I'm able to with Linux. A quick Google points at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555966), but it looks like it's only for Vista/Server.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this at http://superuser.com/

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for, an SSH server for windows: http://superuser.com/questions/64058/windows-ssh-servers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you **can** use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to launch a remote shell, rather than just separate commands. Just specify `cmd` as the program:

```
psexec \\1.2.3.4 -u user -p pass cmd
```

although for security reasons, you'll probably want to use SSH. [freeSShd](http://www.freesshd.com/) (server) and [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (client) are more than adequate.

Answer (score 1):

From the superuser.com thread:

http://www.freesshd.com/

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've ever found is using a SSH client, but I only dabble in Windows territory!

Comment: And that worked? It gave you a remote terminal?

Comment: Try http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: It should work just like ssh on linux/mac... (should)...

Answer (score 0):

I've used PsExec, from [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) to run commands on remote systems. Although this won't give you a true, interactive shell, it can be useful for automatic specific tasks on remote machines. The other strength of PsExec is that you do not need to modify the remote system in any way, installing and running PsExec on the "client" machine is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP already includes a Telnet server. You can secure it with IPSEC if you want.