# SSH server installation on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I'm working on a SSH project. For that I setup everything on client side.

But I'm facing a problem on my SSH server. I tried some SSH servers like [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/). I installed the OpenSSH server on my Windows PC according to [these instructions](http://worldgoneweb.com/2011/installing-openssh-on-windows-7/).

It's working fine only when I run the server in debug mode using the command `sshd -ddd`.
Or else it's not taking any command from my SSH clients.

I need some suggestions on how to install and setup the SSH server on Windows.

Comment: i am asking openssh server installation guidance

Comment: If you check your installed services (e.g. by running `services.msc`), does the OpenSSH service appear in the list?  Is it configured for startup type Automatic?

Comment: yes it's running in services(with automatic startup)but it is responding only when i run it in debug mode using sshd -ddd command

Comment: and is the service configured to Log On As "Local System"?  I can confirm that the setup works on my Win7 machine.  Does restarting the service generate any errors? (check your System and Application event logs)

Comment: service is running, but it's listening the commands from the client, it's listening only when i run it in debug mode using this command sshd -d -d -d

Comment: Make sure you cancel your `sshd -d -d -d`, and then restart the OpenSSH service.  Then check your Windows event logs if it still isn't listening, and report whether any error messages are found there.

Comment: The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( OpenSSHd ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: OpenSSHd : PID 5008 : `OpenSSHd' service started.

Comment: The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( sshd ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: sshd : PID 5024 : Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22..

Comment: These are my event logs of opensshd and sshd check once

Comment: Have a look at John T's answer here, he's provided really good screenshots to accompany it:
http://superuser.com/questions/64058/windows-ssh-servers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recently released its own build of [OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH).

See my guide for setting up [SSH/SFTP server on Windows using this Microsoft build of OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server).

It does not have a dependency on Cygwin or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following instructions which worked successfully on Windows Server 2008 R2 which shares the same codebase as Windows 7:

1. Logon to the Windows machine as a local administrator
2. Download [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) installer
3. Run setup program
4. From package selection expand **Net** category and select **OpenSSH**
5. Finish the installation
6. Run the Cygwin terminal as Administrator (elevated command prompt)
7. Run the **ssh-host-config** program
8. Answer **yes** to **Should privilege separation be used?**
9. Answer **yes** to **Should this script create a local user ‘sshd’ on this machine?**
10. Answer **yes** to **Do you want to install sshd as a service?**
11. Answer **no** to **Should this script create a new local account ‘ssh_server’ which has the required privileges?**
12. When prompted for a username and password for the service, enter an
    existing local Windows account that has administrator privileges
13. Answer **ntsec tty** for **Which value should the environment variable
    CYGWIN have when sshd starts?**
14. Finish the configuration
15. Start the service with **net start sshd**