# FileZilla can not connect to Windows

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla, windows-server

I have a FileZilla software in my Mac, it can connect to the Linux system by 22 port.

but I can not use it connect to Windows Server. With the bellow information:

```
Status:     Retrying...
Status:     Connecting to 45.204.24.28...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    open "administrator@45.204.24.28" 22
Error:  Connection refused
Error:  Cannot connect to Server
```

What should I do for connect it?

---

**EDIT-01**

Now I have installed the `freeSSHd` in Windows Server. but I still can not access.

```
Error:  authentication failure.
Error:  Fatal error: unable to connect to the server.
```

Comment: Do you have SSH server installed on the Windows Server?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Can you recommend how to install it. I created a FTP site. but seems I can not access to.

Comment: Please, don't use freeSSHd. It's a crappy software that has not been updated for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not come with an SSH/SFTP server by default (contrary to e.g. Linux). Adding an FTP site won't help. FTP is not SFTP.

---

You have to install some SSH/SFTP. Windows 10 have it as an optional component. For older versions of Windows, you have to install some separately.

For that, see:

- [SSH server installation on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/444693/213663#1195613) or
- [Windows SSH Servers?](https://superuser.com/q/64058/213663) (with some answers being pretty outdated)